# jquery append() not writing closing tag

Tags: jquery, append

I'm having an odd issue with jquery append method in Google Chrome where it is not writing a closing tag when the element is empty but will if the element contains a character.

If I use this code:

```
$('#workZone .canvas').each(function(i) {
        $(this).append('<canvas id="test"></canvas>');
    });
}
```

I get this in the markup:

```
<canvas id="test">
```

If I use this code:

```
$('#workZone .canvas').each(function(i) {
        $(this).append('<canvas id="test">i</canvas>');
    });
}
```

the I get what I'd expect to get in the markup:

```
<canvas id="test">i</canvas>
```

I'd like the closing tag, obviously, but without having to include the throwaway character.  What is going on?

Here is a test case on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YSDnk/

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: Could you please reproduce it on jsfiddle?

Comment: Use it like its supposed to be used :)  _When authors use the canvas element, they **must** also provide content that, when presented to the user, conveys essentially the same function or purpose as the bitmap canvas. This content may be placed as content of the canvas element. The contents of the canvas element, if any, are the element's fallback content._ [canvas](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element)

Comment: Same happens with a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).append('<canvas id="test"><!-- //comment --> </canvas>');
```

You should put a html comment in empty spaces.
This way the closing tag will show.

Comment: That doesn't address the issue he is having.  He doesn't want to display the character, he want's the closing tag to appear.

Comment: thats exactly what it will do, the comment is ignored even if its there but it seems to be required sometimes. And it will show the closing tag.

Comment: OK, I think this is best response, but to understand look at Andreas's comment in response to my question, and acolchado's answer.  Maybe what is going on is that Chrome web inspector is recognizing that the markup is technically invalid and so not showing the end tag even though it does in fact exist in the DOM in browser's memory.

Comment: I dont know why to be honest, i just know it works like that because i had the same issue and i just figured out by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are verifying this, but you are getting a full tag with your initial code. When I look at the Inspector I see what you see, but if run this in the console:

```
console.log($("#workZone .canvas").html())
```

In the print out you will see the full HTML as valid and properly closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same solution posted earlier, but with a blank space between the tags, in case the comment doesn't solve it.

```
$(this).append('<canvas id="test">&nbsp</canvas>');
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you use:

```
$(this).append('<canvas id="test"/>');
```

This is supposed to be equivalent to what you have, so I don't know why it would work, I've just learned to test all the quircks.